# how to remove qt keyboard support for qtwebbroser from qt5.7

Tags: yocto, openembedded, qtwebengine, qt5.7

I am using yocto morty version qt5.7 and qtwebbrowser. now I want to remove keyboard support in qtwebbrowser.
I have opened `qtwebbrowser_git.bb` and removed
`RDEPENDS_${PN} ="qtvirtual keryboard"`

compiled successfully but when i run the qtwebbrowser on the board its showing below error.

```
qrc:///qml/AppMain.qml:7:9: Type Keyboard unavailable
qrc:///qml/Keyboard.qml:31:1: module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard" is not installed
```

why it is still searching for keyboard. even i removed from recipe.

Is there anything i missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Qt WebBrowser manual](http://doc.qt.io/QtWebBrowser/) (see below in section "Platform Requirements") the "Qt Virtual Keyboard" module is required. As the module is required by Qt WebBrowser itself, I don't see an easy way how to remove the dependency. It needs to be done on Qt WebBrowser level and after that on OpenEmbedded level.

Comment: @Siva.V, sorry, I'm not a lawyer. I can point you to the Licensing FAQ: https://www1.qt.io/FAQ/

Comment: sry, i mean , i saw it have GPLv3 and commercial. any way  thank s for help.

Comment: @Siva.V hmm, there is no LGPL for Qt Virtual Keyboard, but for Qt Core and other modules the LGPL licensing exists... I don't know the communication model between keyboard module and how licensing apply. And anyway, this is another question.